# Create a Button inside a loop with a popup - jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I use this code to create buttons inside a loop, while parsing XML:

```
$('#button' + counter + paramcounter).click(function(){
   sendData(escape(parameterarray[cnt2] + $('#textinput' + cnt + cnt2).val()));
   alert("data send");
});
```

I want to replace the ugly alert popup with a nice jQuery popup. I tried the standard jQuery Mobile popups, but they didn't work inside my click function. I dont want to change the html code.

Thanks fluxim

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/dialog/modal.html  http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in html set a new html  with the use of  jquery mobile linbrary

```
<div data-role="popup" id="popupBasic">
    <p>This is a completely basic popup, no options set.<p>
</div>
```

**in js**

```
$('#button' + counter + paramcounter).click(function(){
   sendData(escape(parameterarray[cnt2] + $('#textinput' + cnt + cnt2).val()));

$( "#popupBasic" ).popup( "open" )
});
```

reference **[popup](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/popup/)**